# Xampp does not make relationship and Wamp does it ,using mirgrations Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, wamp, mariadb

Six months ago, I used Laravel with Xampp, I used migrations and  all worked fine.

Now in Wamp, I got an error . When I run `php artisan migrate` I can watch the tables are there , but the relationship does not. I checked in designer mode on phpmyadmin.

I tried Xampp, and when I run `php artisan migrate` I can watch the tables are there , and the relationship too. I checked in designer mode on phpmyadmin.

I read that Xampp uses MariaDB and Wamp Mysql , but when I used Xampp six months ago I remenber that Xampp was using Mysql too.

I cannot understand why I have not changed Database configuration and I can connect with both .  Can you see what is wrong ? . I know MariaDB is almost the same with Mysql, but ,I can not understand why I cannot  create relationship with migrations on Wamp , I need to use Wamp

Here my files .

Database.php

```
   'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,



    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:O+sV9+HC6/sg1PE4blPO4iJVlxmvJwVMJkO14O0HRL0=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=expediente_orto
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: please check MySQL versions provide by xampp and wamp. may they are different.

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod MariaDB is the same with Mysql ? . Xampp uses MariaDB and Wamp Mysql. In my Database files I use the same configuration and I got conected.

Comment: hi, i don't have more knowledge about DB but you can found some thing useful at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . MariaDB uses InnoDB engine by default , but ,Mysql uses MyISAM by default , the last one does not support relationships.

I changed Database.php to use InnoDB by default. It worked out.

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```